# How to displace one array of int values?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, entity-framework, linq

I have a database with 60 values on a table, the values are filled every minute automatically. I have a query that the first time will take those 60 values and fill the array of `int`s.

However every minute this method is executed with SignalR and the logic should be that the position 0 of the array should be replaced with position 1, position 1 with 2 and so ON, and the last one (59!) must be filled with the last value from the database.

I don't want to recreate the array every minute and even less make a select to the database that returns 60 rows every time.

The code I have is as follows

```
public class Chart_Broadcaster
{
    //The Line Chart Class    
    public class LineChart
    {
        [JsonProperty("lineChartData")]
        private int[] lineChartData;
        [JsonProperty("colorString")]
        private string colorString;

        [JsonProperty("hora")]
        private string[] hora = new string[60];

        public void SetLineChartData()
        {               
            //Suppose we have a list of 60 items.
            using (ZigBeeContext db = new ZigBeeContext())
            {
                var lista = (from p in db.Medidas orderby p.FechaHora descending
                                    select p                             
                             ).Take(60).ToList();

                lineChartData = db.Medidas.Select(p => p.Temperatura).Cast<int>().ToArray();
                hora = db.Medidas.Select(p => p.FechaHora).Cast<string>().ToArray();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [`Queue<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of an array perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice method would be to use a queue instead of an array. From the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Represents a first-in, first-out collection of objects

This means that you just need to [push](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t249c2y7(v=vs.110).aspx) new items onto the bacl of the queue and [pop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c8bzx97(v=vs.110).aspx) old ones off the front. There's no need to worry about positioning and shuffling the items along one spot every time as this is all handled for you.

So when you get a new value to add, you just do this:

```
//For example (you can't do this but it demonstrates the contents of the queue
var queue = new Queue<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } 

var newInt = 6;
queue.Enqueue(newInt);
var oldInt = queue.Dequeue(); //Or don't even bother storing it if you don't want it
```

Another funky method would be to use the Reactive Extensions for .Net ([system.reactive](/questions/tagged/system.reactive)). That works nicely with SignalR as a queuing system.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [Queue class.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx)

You would still have to do a SELECT every minute since I'm assuming you will have a new row every minute (if not then you will have to create logic to only SELECT the new rows from the database). Simply push that row onto the in memory queue and de-queue the first row.

Just FYI that creating an int array of length 60 is trivial and just doing that every minute with a database call sounds perfectly acceptable to me.

Comment: Did you mean to link to the old queue class rather than the new generic version?

Comment: @DavidG well spotted!